# Relative path for Forms Authentication cookie

Tags: cookies, forms-authentication

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="ASPAuth" 
         path="/Admin" 
         timeout="20" 
         requireSSL="false" 
         slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

On my dev system I have the above in my web.config. This works fine if I am using VS web server. But when I host the same website on my IIS7 using a virtual directory it doesn't.

VS Url looks like: http://localhost:xxxx/

IIS URL looks like: http://MachineName/MyApp/.

When accessing the website through IIS the IsAuthenticated is always false. I figured out that it's because the cookie is being assigned to http://MachineName/Admin/ not http://MachineName/MyApp/Admin.

How I make it so that "Admin" is a relative path? I tried path="~/Admin" but that doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

It's simply not possible to do it at this stage. You cannot have a relative path with a tilda (~) in your web.config for forms authentication path unless you're willing to write your own HttpModule.

See this post (and the comments):
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Jan/20/Forms-Authentication-and-path-in-the-forms-Tag

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a transformation into your Web.Release.Config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="ASPAuth"
     path="/MyApp/Admin"
     timeout="20"
     requireSSL="false"
     slidingExpiration="true"
     xdt:Transform="Replace" 
     xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
</authentication>
```